# Read Servlet response in another Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, request, httpclient, response

Here is the situation.
I am invoking Servlet 'A' from Servlet 'B' using the Apache HttpClient Post Method.
Servlet 'A' gets all the data in post method body from Servlet 'B' and processes it successfully, and generates a response in "text/html;charset=UTF-8" format.

I want this response to be stored in a String in Servlet 'B'.
In Short I want to read the response of Servler 'A' in Servlet 'B'

How can I do it ?

Comment: Same way you do in any usage of HttpClient: read its InputStream.

Comment: I am trying with it, but it doesnt seems HttpClient has anything to read from.
Can you help me with an example.

Comment: What you're doing is reading the response from a server, regardless if the other server uses a Servlet or any other technology to write the response. If there's no useful data in the response of the other server, then look at how the response is being written there.